# Como redirecionar para outra API, quando os dados enviados estiverem errados?

Tags: c#, asp.net, middleware

O que acontece é o seguinte, estou fazendo uma parte do sistema que irá fazer a integração dos dados dos clientes. A ideia planejada foi a seguinte, o cliente irá acessar a API para fazer a persistência dos dados, nesta API haverá a persistência dos dados em uma tabela com o nome de cliente_vendas, se os dados estiverem certos, o registro será realizado na tabela e pronto. Porém se os dados estiverem errados, a persistência deve ocorrer em outra tabela, ou seja, se houver algum dado errado vamos supor o cliente manda um dado do tipo string, mas aquela propriedade era do tipo Int, neste caso a persistência não será realizada, na primeira tabela, e sim na segunda tabela com o nome de correcao_vendas. Porém o Asp.Net é muito tipado então não posso receber dados errados, que ele já cai fora da requisição. Alguém tem ideia de como resolver?

Bem no meu caso o que já consegui desenvolver foi isso daqui:

```
public static class ProblemDetailsExtensions{

public static IServiceCollection ConfigureProblemDetailsModelState(this IServiceCollection services)
{
    return services.Configure<ApiBehaviorOptions>(options =>
    {
        options.InvalidModelStateResponseFactory = context =>
        {
            var problemDetails = new ValidationProblemDetails(context.ModelState)
            {
                Instance = context.HttpContext.Request.Path,
                Status = StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest,
                Detail = "Please refer to the errors property for additional details"
            };

            return new BadRequestObjectResult(problemDetails)
            {
                ContentTypes = { "application/problem+json", "application/problem+xml" }
            };
        };
    });
}}
```

public class Startup{

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)  {
    services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);
    services.ConfigureProblemDetailsModelState();
}
```

}

Então o que esta ocorrendo até agora é o seguinte, se houver algum erro no model State, ou seja, se houver algum dado errado, ele irá para este Middleware e irá retornar a resposta do jeito definido ali.
O que acontece em ProblemDetailsExtensions eu gostaria de ao invés de retornar esta mensagem de erro, eu gostaria de redirecionar a minha API para outra API e lá fazer a persistência em outra tabela.

Comment: Não sei se entendi muito bem... mas não seria o caso de você validar o input e responder com um bad request, caso o payload esteja errado?

Comment: Resolvi o problema, eu recebi os dados tudo como string, ai eu trato eles depois! Assim deu certo!